# Configuration with name 'default' not found when I am trying to add library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio and trying to add library named MaterialEditText from github link :[MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) and I follow below steps:

1)Create directory named "libraries" and put the contents of .zip file(MaterialEditText)

2)
`include ':libraries:MaterialEditText-master'` in setting.gradle file of myapp

3)Add dependencies inbuild.gradle file of myapp

```
compile project(':libraries:MaterialEditText-master')
```

and when I click on build project it shows en error

Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

How to fix it?

Comment: what do you have under the folder MaterialEditText-master?

Comment: This error message means that it's not finding a usable **build.gradle** file at the project path libraries:MaterialEditText-master. You should point it at the build file if there is one, and if there is one there, then there's some problem with it (maybe a lack of an `apply plugin` statement) that prevents it from being used to compile a module. If the library doesn't have a build script, you'll need to create one.